# How to Validate DataGrid CheckBoxColumn?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I made a app that function is a download file from sql. For this i add a datagrid with button and checkboxcolumn columns.

The function with button works fine but i can't download files by the selected rows columns.

Can you help me with this.

this is my code:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Threading

Public Class Activity
Public Setfile As Integer
Public drv As DataRowView
Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    txtId.Content = Log_Name
    txtName.Content = EmpNombre & " " & EmpApPat & " " & EmpApMat
    txtSite.Content = Log_Site
    txtType.Content = Log_Type
    'load files
    GetFilesFromDatabase()
    'reset idle counter
    ResetAutoIdleTimeCounter()
End Sub

Private Sub btnUpFile_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnUpFile.Click
    If Log_Type = "ADMIN" Then
        Dim NUpl As New file_upload()
        NUpl.ShowDialog()
    Else
        lblstatus.Content = "Access Denied."
        lblstatus.Foreground = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
        lblstatus.Opacity = 1
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub GetFilesFromDatabase()
    Try
        querySQL = "SELECT file_Id as ID, file_title as FILENAME, file_mimetype as EXTENSION, file_rev as REVISION, file_upl as [DATE UPLOADED], file_pub as [UPL BY] FROM tbl_file"
        sqlDS = New DataSet
        dgFiles.Columns.Clear()
        sqlConn.Open()
        sqlCmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(querySQL, sqlConn)
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        sqlAdap = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
        sqlAdap.Fill(sqlDS, "FileStore")
        sqlConn.Close()
        dgFiles.DataContext = sqlDS '.Tables("FileStore").DefaultView

        Dim dgCheckColum As New DataGridCheckBoxColumn
        dgCheckColum.Header = "SEL"
        dgCheckColum.DisplayIndex = 0


        Dim dgDownColumn As New DataGridTemplateColumn
        dgDownColumn.Header = "FILE"
        dgDownColumn.DisplayIndex = 1
        Dim factory As New FrameworkElementFactory(GetType(Button))
        factory.SetValue(Button.ContentProperty, "Download")
        factory.SetValue(Button.WidthProperty, CDbl(75))
        factory.SetValue(Button.HeightProperty, CDbl(35))
        factory.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, New RoutedEventHandler(AddressOf button_Click))
        Dim cellTemplate As New DataTemplate()
        cellTemplate.VisualTree = factory
        dgDownColumn.CellTemplate = cellTemplate
        dgFiles.Columns.Add(dgCheckColum)
        dgFiles.Columns.Add(dgDownColumn)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        MessageBox.Show("Could not load the File")
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    Try
        Dim SelId As Integer
        drv = dgFiles.CurrentCell.Item
        SelId = drv.Row(0).ToString()
        DownloadFile(SelId, drv.Row(1).ToString(), drv.Row(2).ToString())
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        MessageBox.Show("Could not load the File")
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub DownloadFile(ByVal Id As Integer, ByVal filename As String, ByVal ext As String)
    Try
        querySQL = "SELECT file_bin FROM tbl_file WHERE file_id=@id"
        sqlConn.Open()
        sqlCmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(querySQL, sqlConn)
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id)
        'get image data from db
        fileData = DirectCast(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
        Dim Gig As Long = 1073741824
        For Each drive As System.IO.DriveInfo In System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives
            If drive.DriveType = IO.DriveType.Removable AndAlso drive.IsReady AndAlso drive.AvailableFreeSpace >= 1 * Gig Then
                Dim DriveLetter As String = drive.Name
                Dim PathToUSBDrive = DriveLetter & IO.Path.GetFileName(filename.ToString.Trim & ext.ToString.Trim)
                Using fs As New FileStream(PathToUSBDrive, FileMode.Append)
                    fs.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length)
                    FileOK = True
                    lblstatus.Content = "Done."
                    lblstatus.Foreground = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.LawnGreen)
                    lblstatus.Opacity = 1
                    'Set image variable value using memory stream. 
                    fs.Close()
                    FileOK = True
                End Using
            Else
                lblstatus.Content = "Error: Check if the memory is not full or damaged."
                lblstatus.Foreground = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
                lblstatus.Opacity = 1
            End If
        Next
        sqlConn.Close()
        If FileOK = True Then
            'fill the activity table
            SaveAct(Log_Id, drv.Row(0), True, "The user " & Log_Id & " have downloaded the file " & filename & "." & ext & ". Rev " & drv.Row(3).ToString())
        End If
        'Clear row values
        drv = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        MessageBox.Show("Could not load the File")
    Finally
        sqlConn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub LoadAct(ByVal Id As Integer)
    Try
        sqlDS = New DataSet
        sqlConn.Open()
        sqlCmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SP_CHKACT", sqlConn)
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id)
        sqlAdap = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
        sqlAdap.Fill(sqlDS, "Activity")
        sqlConn.Close()
        dgHist.DataContext = sqlDS '.Tables("FileStore").DefaultView
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    Finally
        sqlConn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Window_Activated(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
    LoadAct(Log_Name)
End Sub

Private Sub Window_PreviewKeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.PreviewKeyDown
    ResetAutoIdleTimeCounter()
End Sub

Private Sub Window_PreviewMouseDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles MyBase.PreviewMouseDown
    ResetAutoIdleTimeCounter()
End Sub
Private Sub ResetAutoIdleTimeCounter()

    ' Or DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle
    Dim timer = New DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                                    DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,
                                   New Action(Sub()
                                                  For intCounter As Integer = Application.Current.Windows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                                                      If Application.Current.Windows(intCounter) IsNot Application.Current.MainWindow Then
                                                          Application.Current.Windows(intCounter).Close()
                                                      End If
                                                  Next
                                              End Sub),
                                    Application.Current.Dispatcher)
End Sub

Private Sub btnOk_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click
    'load files
    GetFilesFromDatabase()
    'reset idle counter
    ResetAutoIdleTimeCounter()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

so when you say you want to only download the selected files are you saying that when you click `button_Click` you'll want to call your download function for any of the rows you have selected in your datagrid?